# Functional sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that for any $(x_n)$ convergent to $x$ we have $f_n(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$.

Prove that $f$ in continuous, there is no assumption about $f_n$'s continuity.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: I need to delete the answer below Hagrid. Can you please unaccept the answer so I can do that?